# Java AST parser for .Net

Tags: c#, java, .net, abstract-syntax-tree

I am looking for a parser, that can extract the abstract syntax tree from a java code. The parser must work under .Net - I need to run it from C#. I know about ANTLR, but I did not find any grammar, that can generate AST as a tree (instead of a flat list).
Can anyone help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: You didn't look real hard, in that case.

Comment: If I Google for "antlr java grammar", I find [this](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) page which lists many Java grammars. At least one of those grammars outputs an AST instead of a flat parse tree/list.

Comment: I am blind. I have seen that list before, but I have thought, there has been only one Java 1.6 and one 1.5 grammar. But now I see, there are more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ain't sure if it helps, but [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) can generate the AST for you, it has a few Java grammar definition (like [this](http://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/download/contrib/grammars/Java1.5.zip), but take a look on the [alternatives](http://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/directory/contrib/grammars)), and the developers [recently added C++ code generation](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.javacc.user/2079). That you might be able to link with C#.